# need help with Binary Patterns.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Write `0.1, 0.2, and 0.3` in fixed point notation as repeating binary patterns. Use your ability to sum an infinite geometric series `5` to show your answers are correct.

Comment: So where did you get stuck?

Comment: @fgp I have no idea where to start. What should i use etc.

Comment: You're supposed to take $0.1$, which is one-tenth, and write it in binary, that is, $1/10=a/2+b/4+c/8+d/16+\cdots$, where each of $a,b,c,d,\dots$ is either 0 or 1. Well, $a$ can't be 1, as $1/2>1/10$. Also $b=c=0$, but $d=1$. What about $e$? $f$? Keep going until you see a pattern. For the second part, do you know the formula for the sum of a geometric series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{1}{3}=0.\overline3$ in decimal. if you multiply that by 3 you get $0.\overline9=1$.

We would like to find a patter we can repeat that yields a bunch on $1$'s when multiplied by $10,5$ and $\frac{10}{3}$ repectively.

$3$ in binary is $11$ and when multiplied by $5$ it is $1111$. therefore the number $0.\overline{0011}\cdot5=1$

If we already know $0.\overline{0011}\cdot5=1$ then $0.0\overline{0011}\cdot10=1$

$3\cdot3=9,9$ is $1001$ in binary. So $0.0\overline{1001}\cdot\frac{10}{3}=1$